# Timer in CF doesn't ticks

Tags: c#, timer, delegates, compact-framework

I develop software for a data collector that uses Compact Framework.

I'm doing a check for every method I'm calling and I'll count the time this method takes to perform. If this time is greater than or equal to 1 minute, then I'm gonna throw an Exception. I have this:

```
    public static TResult Call<TResult>(Func<TResult> closure)
    {
        int ellapsedSeconds = 0;
        Timer timer = new Timer { Interval = 1000, Enabled = true };
        timer.Tick += delegate
        {
            ellapsedSeconds++;
            if (ellapsedSeconds < 60) return;
            timer.Enabled = false;
            throw new Exception(@"TimeOut Error Again!");
        };

        try
        {
            TResult result = closure.Invoke();
            timer.Enabled = false;
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            throw;
        }
    }
```

I know that there are other ways to check, but I'm not looking to change this. I posted my problem domain for you be inside this, but the true problem is that `Timer` doesn't fire tick events. It doesn't have an extension method called `.Start()` or `.Stop()`, like there is for a desktop application. And `timer.Enabled = true;` doesn't start to tick.
Look in:

[image]

How can I start a Timer with compact framework?

Comment: Are you blocking the UI thread at all?

Comment: The Timer is local to the method. It's probably being GC'd before it thought about ticking,

Comment: It is really local to a method. I can't apply as a global member because is a static class.

Comment: He is, if he's calling `Call` from the UI thread then either the call to `Invoke` finishes and the timer is disabled or the `Invoke` throws an exception in which case the timer is disabled too. In other words: the timer can't tick until you exit from `Call` at which point the timer is already disabled again.

Comment: @TonyCamargo You can have a private static field in a static class

Comment: Why aren't you using a Threading Timer, which is far more appropriate for this sort of use case?

Answer (score 3):

Timer relies on windows message pump that is placed on the caller thread. You won't receive any TimerTick events this way.

Try using `BeginInvoke` technique instead. The technique is described in this article - [Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

There are two timers: one in System.Windows.Forms and one in System.Threading.Thread.

The Forms based timer needs a running message pump as it send WM_TIMER messages that are issuing the Tick event handler. The Tick handler will not be called if the GUI is blocked and it will not run when the device is suspended. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer_members%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
The Forms timer does not have a Start() or Stop() method but is started and stopped when you use Enabled=true and false.

The Thread based timer uses a thread and calls the callback when elapsed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.90%29.ASPX

You have chosen the Forms timer, which is the wrong one for the purpose (check if GUI or APP is hanging), as this timer is not called if the message pump is blocked. You should switch to the Thread timer.